# azure sails the hook 'orm' is taking too long

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am following this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-nodejs-sails-cli-nodejs

In section "Connect to a database in Azure"
step 10, I am getting the error:

`Error: The hook 'orm' is taking too long to load. Make sure it is triggering its 'initialize()' callback, or else set 'sails.config.orm._hookTimeout to a higher value (currently 20000)`

I get this error when I "sails lift"

I tried editing the loadhook.js folder to increase the timeout. No luck.

All the other steps went smoothly. The mongo db is running on azure. I added the

`models: {
     connection: 'docDbMongo',
     migrate: 'alter'
 },`

to both development.js and production.js but in production.js i have migrate 'safe' just like in the guide.

What do I do now?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I found that property `port` is missing within object `docDbMongo` in step 7 called "*[Open config/local.js and add the following connections object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-nodejs-sails-cli-nodejs#connect-to-a-database-in-azure)*". I thought that raised your issue.

```
connections: {
    docDbMongo: {
        user: "<database user>",
        password: "<database password>",
        host: "<database hostname>",
        port: "10250", // add this line to config/local.js
        database: "<database name>",
        ssl: true
    },
},
```